# Flutter: Count the API calls via Interceptors

Tags: flutter, interceptor

Is it possible to count the API calls via Interceptors?

For example: If an API (with the same parameters and same endpoint) gets called more than three times, I will show a popup widget.

Comment: You can do that.

Comment: Do you have an example of that? Or any article?

Comment: If using Dio, you can create custom interceptor and save all the request going through it. If not, you will have to cook something on your own.

Comment: [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#dio-api)

Comment: In my case not using Dio but using from native side. But yes, it's possible. I just finished. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to count API calls via interceptors in Flutter. using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio/install) Package

here is  a example :-

```
import 'dart:js';

import 'package: flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('API Calls Counter Demo'),
     ),
     body: Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: _fetchData,
        child: const Text('Fetch Data'),
       ),
     ),
    ),
   );
   }

  void _fetchData() async {
   final dio = Dio();
   const key = 'http://localhost:8080/police/';
   int count = 0;
  }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('API Calls Counter Demo'),
     ),
     body: Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: _fetchData,
        child: const Text('Fetch Data'),
       ),
     ),
    ),
   );
   }




   dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
    onRequest: (options, handler) {
     if (options. Path == key && count++ >= 8) {
      _showPopupWidget(context as BuildContext);
    }
    handler. Next(options);
    },
   ));

  try {
   final response = await dio.get(key);
  print(response.data);
  } catch (e) {
   print(e);
  }
 }

void _showPopupWidget(BuildContext context) {
   showDialog(
   context: context,
   builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
    title: const Text('API Calls Counter'),
    content: const Text('This API has been called more than 8 times.'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        child: const Text('OK'),
      ),
    ],
   ),
  );
 }
```